# Plotting histogram or scatter plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import education
list_of_record = education.get_all_states

virginia_education = education.get_state('Virginia')
enrollment = virginia_education ["enrollment"]
students = enrollment ["students"]
race = students ["race"]

asian = race["asian"]
biracial = race["biracial"]
hispanic = race ["hispanic"]
white = race ["white"]
black = race["black"]
native_american = race["native american"]

all_race = [asian, biracial, hispanic, white, black, native_american]

plt.hist (all_race)
plt.show ()
```

**Image of current histogram:**

[image: Image of current histogram]

I want to change it so it has the names of all the races. the numbers on the x and y-axis are wrong and I am not sure how to fix it

Some of the data:

[image]

Comment: It would be great if you could include a (small) subset of your actual data into the code into the question. That way, people that are trying to help you can immediately run your example, fiddle with it, and have a way to verify their potential solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to use instead is a bar chart. Histograms are used for examining the distribution of numerical data. Here is how I would implement it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import education
list_of_record = education.get_all_states

virginia_education = education.get_state('Virginia')
enrollment = virginia_education["enrollment"]
students = enrollment["students"]
race = students["race"]

x = range(len(race)) # x-axis list
label = [] # x-labels list
y = [] # y-values list
for race, value in race.items():
    label.append(race) # add race to x-labels list
    y.append(value) # add value to y-values list

plt.bar(x,y,color='indianred',tick_label=label,align='center')
plt.show()
```